# Measuring line input in attribute table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, line, measurements

I'm using QGIS 3.10.0 A Coruna.

I have a polygon layer (buildings) where I would like to measure each side depending on its geographic direction (north, east,...).

I'm using the tool `"Measure Line"`, but I have to manually write the value in my attribute table. Is there a way to automatically calculate/have it saved in my attribute table?

Comment: Do you what to have a length of each side separately or just the perimeter of a building? Are buildings polygons or just enclosed polylines?

Comment: I want to have the length of each side seperately.

Comment: Can you be so kind and provide a sketch of your desired output? This is not really clear to me `"to measure each side depending on its geographic direction (north, east,...)"`, can you elucidate it? What defines the direction of the building wall?

Comment: I found a different way of solving my problem. I changed my building layer from polygon to shape and had the field calculator measure each line. Just to clarify what my task was: We have buildings and we needed to simulate the amount of energy and heat, thats why we needed to know the exact length of each side of the building and its geography (north, east, ...). In the first step I used to measuring tool and entered it manually in the attribute table, which was a lot of work - so I chose a work around.